# Custom pages on php for each row on an SQL table?

Tags: php, sql

How can I have custom pages for each row of an sql table? Without having to manually create each one of course.
Say for example I have a table of usernames with their details. I would like it so that theres a unique page for this user that shows all his/her details. This page should be changed whenever the user updates their details of course.

I don't really know what this kind of pages are called and would like links or codes to references on how to achieve this.

Cheers.

Comment: Another example would be stackoverflow. When a question is created, a unique page is made so people can see it.

Comment: there's one page for all the questions. Actually you should learn a little bit more of PHP. It is called template.

Comment: Yes I know it's one page (a template) for all questions, I just want to know how this can be achieved. Thanks. Edit: I think I rememeber this requires use of .htaccess? I remember my wiki for it to have direct links rather than ?whatever=something I had to edit that.

Comment: That is only necessary if you want to use url rewriting to make nice page url's, like `example.com/users/Kenny` and `example.com/users/mellamokb` instead of for example `example.com/users.php?userid=123`.

Comment: @mellamokb Yes, that's what I'm really trying to go for. First I'll use your method to make the user page, then make it look nicer after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, there is a single page that handles the display of all of the records, using a parameter to identify which record should be shown.  The simplest method is through the querystring, so that `example.com/userinfo.php?userid=1` would show details for user #1, and `example.com/userinfo.php?userid=2` would show details for user #2 etc.

When you are writing the `userinfo.php` page as above, you can use code like the following to display the correct user:

```
<?php
// check that user id was passed in query string
if (isset($_GET['userid'])) {
    $userid = (int)$_GET['userid'];
    // create sql query to lookup user details and store
    // in variables like $username, $displayname, etc.
    // AND USE PREPARED STATEMENTS! mind you
    // don't inject the variable into strings and allow SQL injection
} else {
    // display error page that user id is not valid, or default page
    // or redirect to home page, etc.
}

// display user details using HTML from data looked up
?>
<p>Username: <?php =$username ?></p>
<p>Display Name: <?php =$displayname ?></p>
.. etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, this might just work. I'll work on it now and see how that goes :)